# How do I use applescript to save a Microsoft Word document in a specific Finder folder?

Tags: applescript

How do I use applescript to save a file in a specific folder?

I have a script that creates a document, but I haven't yet figured out how to save the file where I want. Here is the relevant (I believe) code:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    tell active document
        save as file name SaveName
    end tell
end tell
```

With this, the file saves to the users Documents folder. I feel like there must be a simple way to tell it to save it in a specific location, but everything I've searched and tried thus far hasn't led to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a full path for example if you want to save the file to the desktop folder

```
set desktopFolder to path to desktop as text
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    tell active document
        save as file name (desktopFolder & SaveName)
    end tell
end tell
```

`path to desktop as text` is the equivalent to `"[startup disk]:Users:[current user]:Desktop:"`